# enabling event scheduler causes mysql silent failure

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysqld Ver 5.5.22-0ubuntu1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Ubuntu)) under Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-generic x86_64).  Updates are current.

I had two events that were working fine, and then a power outage knocked the server out.  Since then, mysql will not start if event_scheduler=ENABLED in /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
# service mysql restart
mysql stop/waiting
start: Job failed to start
```

I dropped both events and the event table is empty.

/var/log/mysql.err is completely empty.

There must be some events queued up somewhere but I can't seem to find them.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: /var/log/mysql/error.log doesn't give a whole lot more information:
130624 11:31:46 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

130624 11:31:46 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130624 11:31:48 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 475  user: 'root'

130624 11:31:48  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130624 11:31:49  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 7222402477
130624 11:31:49 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

Here's syslog for the same time period:
Jun 24 11:31:49 earth kernel: [4569993.677493] type=1400 audit(1372098709.303:19): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid" pid=20660 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=102 ouid=102
Jun 24 11:31:49 earth kernel: [4569993.697382] type=1400 audit(1372098709.323:20): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=20666 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 24 11:31:49 earth kernel: [4569993.722622] init: mysql main process (20670) terminated with status 1
Jun 24 11:31:49 earth kernel: [4569993.722650] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Jun 24 11:31:50 earth kernel: [4569994.727981] init: mysql post-start process (20671) terminated with status 1
Jun 24 11:31:50 earth kernel: [4569994.737481] type=1400 audit(1372098710.363:21): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=20694 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 24 11:31:50 earth kernel: [4569994.762575] init: mysql main process (20698) terminated with status 1
Jun 24 11:31:50 earth kernel: [4569994.762602] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Jun 24 11:31:51 earth kernel: [4569995.767984] init: mysql post-start process (20699) terminated with status 1
Jun 24 11:31:51 earth kernel: [4569995.777498] type=1400 audit(1372098711.403:22): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=20722 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 24 11:31:51 earth kernel: [4569995.802326] init: mysql main process (20726) terminated with status 1
Jun 24 11:31:51 earth kernel: [4569995.802354] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped

Comment: according to the documentation event_scheduler=ENABLED should be event_scheduler=ON http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

On newer debian installs the mysql error log goes to syslog by default. Check in /var/log/ there should be mysqld startup logs and maybe some errors related to the mysql.event table.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I looked into the logs and can't really figure out the issue, apart from apparmor denying something.